# Understanding Bubble Sort in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bubble-sort

I'm really confused about how this code works.

Suppose the Inputs for the list are [ C, B, A, exit].

On the first "for" statement, it will swap around the list positions 0 and 1, which are C and B.

This would lead to a new list with [B, C, A]

However, why is it that on the second set of "for" statements, it would swap around A and B instead of C and A? This can be seen in the photo where the output says that it will swap B and A. I'm so confused as to why it would do that when it should be using positions 1 and 2 of the list instead.

I have tried hand-tracing the code and I always get that C and A should have swapped instead. Can someone help explain it to me? Thank you very much in advance

```
def bubble(alist):
    count = 0
    count2 = 0
    for length in range(len(list)):
        for i in range(len(list) - 1):
            if list[i] > list[i + 1]:
                print("Swapping", list[i + 1], list[length])
                tmp = list[length]
                list[length] = list[i+1]
                list[i + 1] = tmp

list = []
while True:
   val = input()
   if val == "exit":
      break
   list.append(val)

counts = bubble(list)
print(list)
```

**Picture of the output**
[image: Picture of the output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comparison

```
if list[i] > list[i + 1]:
```

does not match your swap code

```
tmp = list[length]
list[length] = list[i+1]
list[i + 1] = tmp
```

Either change you comparison to

```
if list[i + 1] > list[length]
```

or change your swap code to

```
tmp = list[i + 1]
list[i + 1] = list[i]
list[i] = tmp
```

Also, you should really never use `list` as a variable name as it is a [built-in type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list).

Comment: Ah. Thank you!. I think I get it now!